# Rule on how to turn flat infinitives into present-tense 3rd-person singulars

Tags: grammar

Is there any rule in English on how to turn flat infinitives into present-tense 3rd-person singulars?

As far as I can see, sometimes it's done by simple concatenation of the flat infinitive and "s":

```
sleep  + s -> sleeps
stay   + s -> stays
enjoy  + s -> enjoys
geno   + s -> genos
gherao + s -> gheraos
```

Sometimes, by changing the last letter (probably only in case of letter 'y' following right after a consonant) into 'ie' first:

```
bully   ->   bullie   + s -> bullies
signify ->   signifie + s -> signifies
cry     ->   crie     + s -> cries
```

Sometimes by concatenation of the flat infinitive and "es":

```
do    + es -> does
go    + es -> goes
video + es -> videoes
```

And sometimes (probably only in one case), by dropping the last two letters first:

```
have -> ha + s -> has
```

Comment: There is a *morpheme* on the end of that 3rd-person singular form in speech. This morpheme has various orthographic manifestations which are mere accidents of spelling conventions which have developed over the centuries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In English, as in most other languages, there are two main types of verbs you need to be aware of when conjugating verbs.

> Regular verbs - This group includes most verbs and they follow the rules below.

All regular verbs use the bare infinitive in the First Person and Second Person for both singular and plural. They also use the bare infinitive in the Third Person plural. However, the Third Person plural always follow the following rules when the tense is in the simple present and you are using the indicative mood:

(a) If the bare infinitive ends in a consonant followed by a 'y', drop the 'y' at the end and add 'ies' to the end of the bare infinitive, e.g. hurry --> he/she/it/one hurries.

(b) If the bare infinitive ends in a vowel other than 'e', or if the bare infinitive ends in any of the following letters ('ch','s', 'sh', 'x' or 'z'), add 'es' to the end of the bare infinitive, e.g. lurch --> he/she/it/one lurches; fess --> he/she/it/one fesses; rush --> he/she/it/one rushes; box --> he/she/it/one boxes; buzz --> he/she/it/one buzzes.

(c) In all other cases, simple add s to the end of the bare infinitive, i.e. fall --> he/she/it/one falls.

> Irregular verbs - Verbs can be irregular for a number of reasons, e.g. how they form the past tense, how they form the past or present participle. For the purpose of this answer, I am only looking at verbs that are irregular in the way in which they form Third Person singular in the simple present when you are using the indicative mood. There are really only two verbs in this category that you need to be aware of:

(a) Be (Highly irregular)   I am, You are, He/she/it/one is, We are, You are, They are

(b) Have (Slightly irregular)  I have, You have, He/she/it/one **has**, We have, You have, They have

Two of the verbs that you mentioned (Geno and Gherao) are not English words, so they are not required to follow these rules. If, with time, these words are adopted into standard English, the Third Person singular will either be amended to fit in with these rules, or they will be added to the list of irregular verbs.